# Trouble referring to defrecord symbols in Clojure unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

Consider the following leiningen project `core.clj` file

```
(ns records.core)

(defn hello []  "hello")

(defprotocol my-sequence
  (add [seqq item]))

(defrecord my-vector [coll]
  my-sequence
  (add [_ item] (conj coll item)))
```

I can compile this and test it in the REPL as follows:

```
records.core> (hello)
"hello"
records.core> (add (my-vector. []) 42)
[42]
```

But when I transcribe this into the leiningen unit-test file as follows:

```
(ns records.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [records.core :refer :all]))

(deftest a-test
  (testing "adding to a my-vector"
    (is (= (hello) "hello"))
    #_(is (= [42] (add (my-vector. []) 42)))))
```

The first test succeeds, showing that symbol `hello` is correctly moved into the `records.core-test` namespace, but the test of `my-vector` throws a compiler error (remove the `#_` on the second line above):

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Unable to resolve classname: my-vector, compiling:  
(.../records/test/records/core_test.clj:8:22)
```

This does not seem to be a duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363216/how-to-avoid-having-to-manually-evaluate-defrecords-and-defprotocols-while-unit) because I am using `require` and `refer`, as the answer to that question suggested.

**EDIT**: the following also do not help

```
(add (records.core/my-vector. []) 42)
(add (#'records.core/my-vector. []) 42)
(add (@#'records.core/my-vector. []) 42)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless my defrecord skills become rusty, you should first require the namespace and then import the defrecord.

```
(:require records.core)
(:import [records.core my-vector])
```

Comment: He could also use the generated constructor function, `->my-vector`, which will be included by require/refer.